# OnPrem TeamCity on Windows cannot pull chnged from Bitbucket repos anymore

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity

All of a sudden the latest version of TeamCity `2021.2 (build 99542)` on Windows cannot pull changes from Bitbucket git repos anymore with the following error:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException
Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read
```

I have:

- updated Java version to `amazon-corretto-11.0.13.8.1`
- Regenerated SSH key

but no luck. Agent is running as a Windows service.

Any suggestions?

More detailed error:

```
Failed to collect changes,
error:
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException:
git@bitbucket.org:[**]/[**].git:
Session.connect:
java.io.IOException:
End of IO Stream Read,
VCS root:
"git@bitbucket.org:[**]/[**].git" {instance id=38, parent internal id=18, parent id=[**]/[**], description: "git@bitbucket.org:[**]/[**].git#refs/heads/test"}
```